# How can i speed up file reading in Pascal?

Tags: pascal

I have this code:

```
program test; 
var 
      testarray: array [1 .. 100000] of longint; 
      a, b: longint; 
      counter: longint; 
      testf: text; 
begin 
      assign (testf, 'test.txt'); 
      reset (testf);
      for counter: = 1 to 10000000 do 
          begin 
              read (testf, a, b); 
              testarray [a]: = testarray [a] +1; 
              testarray [b]: = testarray [b] +1; 
          end; 
       close (testf); 
end.
```

The test.txt file looks like this:

6465 74

97 31

98 146

346 649

.

.

.

eg a = 6465 b = 74

The program takes a long time at this point:

```
for counter: = 1 to 10000000 do 
          begin 
              read (testf, a, b); (* <------ *)
```

How can I speed up the program?

Comment: Well, you could reduce the top value of your counter by a factor of 10 to match the size of your array to start. (Your array is declared with 6 zeros, the loop counter with 7.) You could also check for EOF, so that you don't keep looping when you're out of data. Can you post your *real* code, and then define what "takes a long time" means?

Comment: If using Delphi/Turbo Pascal, you may want to try out the [SetTextBuf](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/System_SetTextBuf@Text@.html) function.

Comment: An aside: the assignment operator `:=` can't have a space in the middle. That's a syntax error. Per @KenWhite comment, you are actually running your loop 100x more than the length of your array. So, indeed, check for EOF and define a constant for the array size and use that as your maximum loop iteration as well.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the **EOF** *(End Of File)* boolean function, which returns *true* if you have reached the end of your text file, and *false* otherwise. With this in mind you have to read the two next numbers only if you have not reached the end of your file yet. So your **while loop** will stop autamtically when it reads the last number(against with your **for loop** ). Using this function you don`t need the **counter** variable. I also find other errors in your code:

```
program test;
var
      testarray: array [1 .. 100000] of longint;
      a, b: longint;
      testf: text;
begin
      assign (testf, 'test.txt');
      reset (testf);
      { - Using EOF instead of for will speed up your program - }
      while not(eof(testf)) do
          begin
              { - If you have 2 numbers in each row you shoud use readln - }
              readln(testf, a, b);
              { - Correct ": =" to ":=" - }
              testarray[a]:= testarray[a] +1;
              testarray[b]:= testarray[b] +1;
          end;
       close (testf);
end.
```